# Conditional homoskedasticity vs heteroskedasticity

Tags: regression, econometrics, heteroscedasticity, assumptions

From *Econometrics*, by Fumio Hayashi (Chpt 1):

Unconditional Homoskedasticity:

- The second moment of the error terms E(εᵢ²) is constant across the observations
- The functional form E(εᵢ²|xi) is constant across the observations

Conditional Homoskedasticity:

- The restriction that the second moment of the error terms E(εᵢ²) is constant across the observations is lifted

  - Thus the conditional second moment E(εᵢ²|xi) can differ across the observations through possible dependence on xᵢ.

So then, my question:

**How does Conditional Homoskedasticity differ from Heteroskedasticity?**

My understanding is that there is heteroskedasticity when the second moment differs across observations (xᵢ).

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://www2.econ.iastate.edu/classes/econ674/falk/Lecture%2016_conditional_heterosked_I.pdf

Comment: There a slight issue in that the lecture says "Therefore, conditional homoskedasticity implies unconditional homoskedasticity" in contradiction to the Econometrics book.  They seem to be conditioning on different things.

Comment: @Henry It is difficult to tell from the present question which definitions are accurate and which ones not--some of them do not seem to make sense out of the context of the textbook.  Some clarification would be welcome.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I will begin by just quoting from Hayashi to help anybody else who would like to comment.  I have tried to preserve formatting and original equation numbers.

Begin quote from Hayashi page 126, section 2.6:

**Conditional versus Unconditional Homoskedasticity**

The conditional homoskedasticity assumption is:

**Assumption 2.7 (conditional homoskedasticity):**
\begin{align*}
\tag{2.6.1} E(\epsilon_i^2|\mathbf{x}_i)=\sigma^2>0.
\end{align*}
This assumption implies that the unconditional second moment $E(\epsilon_i^2)$ equals $\sigma^2$ by the Law of Total Expectations.  To be clear about the distinction between unconditional and conditional homoskedasticity, consider the following example [Example 2.6 (unconditionally homoskedastic but conditionally heteroskedastic errors)...]

End quote.

Some relevant equations from Hayashi pages 11-14 (Section 1.1):
\begin{align*}
\tag{1.1.12} E(\epsilon_i^2|\mathbf{X})=\sigma^2>0 \quad (i=1,2,\ldots,n) \\\
\tag{1.1.17} E(\epsilon_i^2|\mathbf x_i)=\sigma^2>0 \quad (i=1,2,.\ldots,n).
\end{align*}

The subsection "The Classical Regression Model for Random Samples" on page 12 discusses the implications of a sample being iid.  Quoting from Hayashi pages 12-13: "The implication of the identical distribution aspect of a random sample is that the joint distribution of $(\epsilon_i,\mathbf x_i)$ does not depend on $i$.  So the *un*conditional second moment $E(\epsilon_i^2)$ is constant across $i$ (this is referred to as **unconditional homoskedasticity**) and the functional form of the conditional second moment $E(\epsilon_i^2|\mathbf x_i)$ is the same across $i$.  However Assumption 1.4---that the *value* of the conditional second moment is the same across $i$---does not follow.  Therefore, Assumption 1.4 remains restrictive for the case of a random sample; without it, the conditional second moment $E(\epsilon_i^2|\mathbf x_i)$ can differ across $i$ through its possible dependence on $\mathbf x_i$.  To emphasize the distinction, the restrictions on the conditional second moments, (1.1.12) and (1.1.17), are referred to as **conditional homoskedasticity**."

[No further quotes from Hayashi, just my understanding after this point.]

I assume the original question was about the above discussion on pages 12-13.  In that case, I think the first bullet under "Conditional Homoskedasticity" isn't technically correct (though I understand what you mean): Hayashi says (1.1.17) is "conditional homoskedasticity," and if $E(\epsilon_i^2|\mathbf x_i)=\sigma^2$, then $E(\epsilon_i^2)=E[E(\epsilon_i^2|\mathbf x_i)]=E[\sigma^2]=\sigma^2$, as Hayashi notes on page 126 (that conditional homoskedasticity implies unconditional homoskedasticity by the Law of Total Expectations).

So I think part of the issue may be the interpretation of Hayashi's statements.  Conditional homoskedasticity says (1.1.17) even for different $\mathbf x_i$, the variance of $\epsilon_i$ is the same constant $\sigma^2$.  Unconditional homoskedasticity is a *weaker* statement, in that you could have $E(\epsilon_i^2)=\sigma^2$ but $E(\epsilon_i^2|\mathbf x_i)\ne\sigma^2$; Examples 2.6 (page 127) illustrates this.  It also perhaps answers the question of the overlap between homo- and heteroskedasticity: it gives an example where there is unconditional homoskedasticity as well as conditional heteroskedasticity.

These are confusing concepts, especially without a lot of experience with conditional expectations/distributions, but hopefully this adds some clarity (and source material for any future discussions).

Comment: It might help to summarize those examples here to more fully clarify the distinction between these confusing concepts.