# Homoscedasticity - constant second moment or constant variance

Tags: variance, moments, definition

I found the following different definitions of homoscedasticity and I'm wondering which is the correct one.

1. The second moment is constant, i.e. E(X²)=s² (see e.g. p.11 http://press.princeton.edu/chapters/s6946.pdf or [Conditional homoskedasticity vs heteroskedasticity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9322/conditional-homoskedasticity-vs-heteroskedasticity))
2. The variance is constant, i.e. Var(x)=σ² (see e.g. Wooldridge (2006), *Introductory Economics*, p.51 or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoscedasticity)

Since Var(X) = E(X²)–(E(X))², **the two definitions are equivalent if and only if E(X) is constant**.

Which definition is correct is relevant because definition (1) and (2) result in different conditions under which conditional homoscedasticty implies unconditional homoscedasticity.

Under definition (1) conditional homoscedasticty would always imply unconditional homoscedasticity, which can be shown by applying the law of iterated expectations: Denoting the conditional second moment as E(X²|Y)=s², we can write the unconditional second moment as E[X²] = E[E(X²|Y)] = E(s²) = s².

In contrast, under definition (2), conditional homoscedasticty implies unconditional homoscedasticity if and only if **E(X|Y) = E(x)**, because the unconditional variance Var(X) = E[(X–E(X))²] = E[E[(X–**E(X)**)²|Y]]  !=  E[(X-(**E(X|Y)**)²|Y] = Var(X|Y) = σ².

Would be great if someone knew why there are two ways of defining homoscedasticity or where my reasoning is wrong such that both definitions are always equivalent.

Comment: What exactly is "$X$"? I ask because the definition you quote in (1) appears completely different from that found on p. 10 of your first reference (there is no definition appearing on p. 11).  Its definition is $$E(\varepsilon_i^2\,|\,\mathbf{X})=\sigma^2\gt 0\ (i=1,2,\ldots,n)$$ (formula 1.1.12). On p. 11 it is pointed out that this conditional expectation equals the variance because the conditional expectation of $\varepsilon_i$ is zero (the "strict exogeneity" assumption 1.2, p. 7).

Comment: I was referring to „The homoskedasticity assumption (1.1.12) says that the conditional 2nd moment […] is a constant. Thanks to strict exogeneity, this condition can be stated equivalently in more familiar terms. Consider the conditional variance Var(εi|X).”  I understood this and (1.1.12) such that he defines homoscedasticity as a constant 2nd moment and only here, under E(εi|X) = 0 = const., this yields the same result as if homoscedasticity was defined as a constant variance, as in def. (2). Yet, if E(εi|X) = const. wasn't fulfilled, a constant 2nd moment wouldn’t imply a constant variance.

Comment: Possibly, the passage and formula 1.1.12 are meant the other way around: Homoscedasticity means a constant variance, which, in the case of E(εi|X) = 0, means that the second moment is constant. 

As for your question: I used X instead of ε and Y instead of X for better comparability to definition (2). I did not mention the strict exogeneity assumption because I understand that under this assumption definition (1) and (2) are equivalent.

Comment: PS: @whuber (Sorry, I'm new here.)

Comment: Welcome to our site!  Ordinarily, "skedasticity" refers to *scatter* (which is the ancient Greek etymology).  This is measured by the variance, not the second moment. Thus your "possibly" interpretation sounds like the right one.

Comment: $E(\epsilon|X)=0$ is a version of the key assumption that we make that the model is, broadly speaking, correctly specified. If we have a misspecified model, all bets are off as to how anything - test statistics, OLS estimators etc. - we study behaves anyhow.