# Variance as a function of the mean. Why does this affect linear regression?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, variance, linear-model, mean

I'm currently studying university level statistics and I'm struggling to wrap my head around the concept of variance as a function of the mean. How does this affect linear regression and why does it violate the assumption of constant variance? How can you visually assess stable variance?

Comment: Related:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68710/heteroskedasticity-residual-plot-interpretation           http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9322/conditional-homoskedasticity-vs-heteroskedasticity